Git en servidor Windows sin internet
Quisiera instalar un GIT en un servidor que tengo, sin acceso a Internet. Estaba pensando en GITEA o GOGS pero ambos al instalarlos me piden cosas para descarga.
¿Existe alguna alternativa similar a los que mencioné anteriormente que no dependa de internet para descargar complementos?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
